# Genymotion won't stop optimizing app

Tags: android, optimization, android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to use Genymotion with Android Studio so that I can test an app, but whenever I try to launch the emulator it says "Android is starting... Optimizing app [#] of 74" and it optimizes for a while. Eventually it stops optimizing, but then it is just a black screen and says "android." Then after a minute or two it goes back to optimizing. How do I get it so that I can actually use the emulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going into my BIOS and enabling `Intel Virtualization Technology` under the CPU Options, and then going into `GenyMotion` and changing the device's # of virtual processors fixed this issue.