# Lollipop Genymotion Emulator keeps on "Optimizing Apps"

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

The app will boot up. Do the "Android Screen" and then go into optimizing apps, x out of 74.

Once done. It will literally repeat this process.

Any tips on how to get out of this?

I already tried what was found here: [Genymotion won't stop optimizing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337674/genymotion-wont-stop-optimizing-app)

And this did not help.

Comment: Martijn Pieters deleted my answer here but, you can find it in the link provided above.

Comment: So this happened to me and the reason was that hyper-v was somehow disabled in my mobo, eventhough I enabled it. I also updated genymotion and reinstalled my Emulator.

Comment: Going into my BIOS and enabling Intel Virtualization Technology under the CPU Options, and then going into GenyMotion and changing the device's # of virtual processors fixed this issue.